# Security issues with opening a Socket with a url and port of an external machine to play streaming audio

Tags: java, sockets, security

Are there any security issues I should be aware of when opening a Socket connection with the url and port of a streaming radio station?  I have written some code to do this, and I am beginning to wonder if there are any security vulnerabilities that I should be aware of.. Any comments on this will be appreciated.

Comment: You could also try to ask of [Information security](http://security.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: @Serge,  yours is the only answer I got since I posted my question a couple of days ago. So it appears the only danger is if the streaming radio station wants to stream something else (besides audio) to my computer.. Don't know what javax.media.Player will do with any malicious bit stream..
Anyway, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather broad...

Here are the security risks I'm thinking of first:

- publish your own address. It is a low risk because you do that at any time you consult an Web site. It can only be dangerous if the streaming radio want to attack its clients
- read the data without limit: if you try to read in memory a streaming flow, you could exhaust your memory and crash the JVM - if you have a high performance connection and a small disk, same could apply to disk.
- process the data in an unsecure way. I do not know what you want to do with that, but as you have not built it, you must not trust it => you should control that what you read seems sane before going further. AFAIK this is the most actual risk - a common rule in security is that the most dangerous thing for a computer lies between the keyboard and the chair.

Comment: yours is the only answer I got since I posted my question a couple of days ago. So it appears the only danger is if the streaming radio station wants to stream something else (besides audio) to my computer.. Don't know what javax.media.Player will do with any malicious bit stream..
Anyway, thanks for your response.